# Why does my Canon SX260HS shut down while I am shooting?

Tags: canon, powershot

I can take like 2 shots then it shuts down. Lens closes. I press restart and then the same thing happens. I miss a lot of shots while restarting. Anything I can do?

This is the message:"A camera error has occurred. Will shut down. Restart camera. E32"

Powershot SX260HS  The camera just shuts down while I'm shooting.

Comment: Have you try to charge battery? Have you try with new battery? Also try to reset the camera.

Comment: What does the manual say to do when you repeatedly encounter this error message? Hint...it's on [page 229](https://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/3/0300007233/01/PowerShot_SX260_HS_SX240_HS_CameraUserGuide_EN_v1.0.pdf). Have you considered that it might be just a small hint that it's time to move on from this particular device? Nothing works forever.

Comment: Does the flash card activity light stay on after you take photos for a really long time?  If so, you could be hitting the watchdog timer; get a different flash card.

Comment: May also be some kind of lens problem: https://community.usa.canon.com/t5/PowerShot/SX280HS-E32-error-not-video/td-p/96410

Comment: Thank you. I had misplaced my manual. I have changed the battery. I will contact the help desk.

Comment: They no longer service this camera. The instructions say to go to "Rest All" but I can't find out how to get there.. I'd like to try it.

Comment: @LindaBHall according to the manual, you just press the Menu button, then you should find Reset All in the tab marked with a wrench/hammer. Note that this option will just reset any settings that you've changed from their defaults. It doesn't do any kind of comprehensive software reinstall or something. Personally, I doubt it will change anything for you, but no harm giving it a shot.

Comment: They no longer service this camera because it is an old camera now. It wouldn't be expected to still be widely in use/service. I appreciate that the price of a new camera is not negligible, but really, moving on from this camera may be your best/only option. Canon do have newer, better options available in their PowerShot SX* range now. What about a smartphone? Do you have one that can shoot photos/videos? How do you think the quality compares between the two devices?